# how to ignore default namespace in struts2

Tags: struts2, namespaces, default-namespace

everyone.
I'm having problem on struts2 namespace..

First of all, this is my developing environment.
server : tomcat
(currently my project is in `ROOT` folder in `/tomcat/webapps/ROOT`)
framework : struts2

Here is my problem.
lets say there are two pages. admin_index.jsp and front_index.jsp
when i want to call admin_index.jsp from action. i use

```html
<package name="admin" namespace="/dl_adm" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="/index" method="index"class="kr.co.www2.controller.front.AdminMainController">
      <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/admin_index.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

and it works fine by calling `http://.../dl_adm/index.do`

and to call this has problem for me.

```html
<package name="front" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="/index" method="index"class="kr.co.www2.controller.front.FrontMainController">
      <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/front_index.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

when i go for the `http://.../index.do`, it gives 404...

although i aware that `namespace="/"` is for default namespace...

QUESTIONS:

1. Is there anyway to ignore the default namespace? because i want to use that `/` because i just want to go through `http://.../` and action name without namespace...
2. or if there isn't a way to do that. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there anyway to ignore the default namespace? because i want to use that / because i just want to go through `http://.../` and action name without namespace..

No, you can't ignore the default namespace. The default namespace is empty and it's used if you omit `namespace` attribute in the package declaration.

---

> 2. or if there isnt a way to do that. any suggestions?

I would not use slashes in action name using xml configuration. The action mapper might incorrectly add an additional slash to the action name to infer the mapping from the URL.

---

So you should use

```xml
<package name="front" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="index" method="index"class="kr.co.www2.controller.front.FrontMainController">
      <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/front_index.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

Comment: ok then i would have to change all the action names in jsp and actionclass. well thank you :)